# What would climate be like on a tidally locked planet?

Tags: planets, weather

How would climate behave on a tidally locked planet? Would there be zones like the ones on earth or not?

Comment: You seem to be asking more about climate than weather.

Comment: Related: [If Earth was tidally locked to the sun, where on the surface would the climate be mildest or most hospitable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/84891/32451). Really, wordbuilding SE has TONS of information regarding tidally locked planets. This question is a duplicate, it's just so difficult to tell a duplicate of what.

Comment: Hi, Leo Fisher. You'll find a great deal of information relevant to your question in the answers at the other end of the links provided in the comments. Also look right and down, you'll see linked and related questions and their attendant answers. I'm sure that the subject's been fairly well surrounded - however, if there's still an issue you can [edit] your question to reflect that.

Comment: Seriously this question has NOTHING TO DO with tidally locked moons.  Those are a totally different deal and those answers are not relevant.

Comment: CLARIFICATION: I was asking about tidally locked planet.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how oceanic the planet is particularly on the dark side.  If there is a large continent on the far side, ice will pile up on it, stealing water away from the dayside. There won't be much weather.  Just desert on one side and a big mass of ice on the other.   If it's mostly ocean then there will be a dark side icecap and probably a perpetual hurricane that stays centered near the west pole with strong winds and ocean currents exchanging heat between the dark and light sides.

The climactic zones would exist in concentric circles based on how far they are away from the east pole (the bit of the planet closest to the sun).